# Stored Procedure not working with insert into temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, global-variables, common-table-expression, insert-into

I have a Stored Procedure and cte not playing nice together. I have tried doing some research and have been unsuccessful. When I comment out insert into the ##tab on the cte the SP works and I see the results of the cte. it's just when I'm inserting into a Global temp table ##tab.

I'm receiving these errors.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 39

Incorrect syntax near 'ALL'.

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 39

Incorrect syntax near 'ALL'.

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 39

Incorrect syntax near 'ALL'.

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 39

Incorrect syntax near 'ALL'.

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 39

Incorrect syntax near 'ALL'.

```
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO




ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[csp_CALL_UCBI_DCN_DATES]
    @FMDATE DATETIME ='2014-01-20 00:00:00.000', 
    @TODATE DATETIME ='2014-06-30 00:00:00.000'
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE 
--@FMDATE DATETIME
--,@TODATE DATETIME
@FM_DATEPART_MONTH VARCHAR(2)
,@FM_DATEPART_YEAR VARCHAR(4)
,@TO_DATEPART_MONTH VARCHAR(2)
,@TO_DATEPART_YEAR VARCHAR(4)

--SET @FMDATE = '2014-01-20 00:00:00.000'
--SET @TODATE = '2014-06-30 00:00:00.000'
SET @FM_DATEPART_MONTH = CAST(DATEPART(M,@FMDATE) AS VARCHAR(2))
SET @FM_DATEPART_YEAR = CAST(DATEPART(YYYY,@FMDATE) AS VARCHAR(4))
SET @TO_DATEPART_MONTH = CAST(DATEPART(M,@TODATE) AS VARCHAR(2))
SET @TO_DATEPART_YEAR = CAST(DATEPART(YYYY,@TODATE) AS VARCHAR(4))

  CREATE TABLE ##tab (id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,myDate VARCHAR(50), SQLname VARCHAR(50),myMonth VARCHAR(50),myYear VARCHAR(50))
;WITH cte(myDate,myMonth,myYear,SQLname) AS (

    SELECT @FMDATE  AS myDate
    ,CAST(DATEPART(M,@FMDATE) AS VARCHAR(2)) AS myMonth
    ,CAST(DATEPART(YYYY,@FMDATE) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS myYear
    ,CAST(DATEPART(M,@FMDATE) AS VARCHAR(2))+'_'+CAST(DATEPART(YYYY,@FMDATE) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS SQLname
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,1,myDate) AS myDate
    ,CAST(DATEPART(M,DATEADD(MONTH,1,myDate)) AS VARCHAR(2)) AS myMonth
    ,CAST(DATEPART(YYYY,DATEADD(MONTH,1,myDate)) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS myYear
    ,CAST(DATEPART(M,DATEADD(MONTH,1,myDate)) AS VARCHAR(2))+'_'+CAST(DATEPART(YYYY,DATEADD(MONTH,1,myDate)) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS SQLname
    FROM cte
    WHERE DATEADD(MONTH,1,myDate) <=  @TODATE
)
INSERT INTO [##tab]
(myDate,myMonth,myYear,SQLname)
SELECT *
FROM cte
--output INSERTED.myDate,INSERTED.myMonth,INSERTED.myYear,INSERTED.SQLname into [##tab]
--(myMonth,myYear,SQLname)
--OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

------------------------------------

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(8000)
, @i INT
,@count INT
, @sqlname VARCHAR(15)
, @myMonth VARCHAR(50) 
, @myYear VARCHAR(50)

SET @i=1
SELECT @count= COUNT(*) FROM ##tab
WHILE @i <= @count

BEGIN
SELECT @SQLname=SQLname, @myMonth=myMonth, @myYear=myYear FROM ##tab WHERE id=@i 

SET @sql = '
  SELECT  
''UCBI_DCE_'+@SQLname+''' AS [Table],
CAST('''+@myMonth+'/'+@myYear+'/01'' AS DATETIME) AS Date,
        lEntity ,
        lValue ,
        lAccount ,
        lICP ,
        lCustom1 ,
        lCustom2 ,
        lCustom3 ,
        lCustom4 ,
        dP0_Input ,
        dP0_InputTransType ,
        dP1_Input ,
        dP1_InputTransType ,
        dP2_Input ,
        dP2_InputTransType ,
        dP3_Input ,
        dP3_InputTransType ,
        dP4_Input ,
        dP4_InputTransType ,
        dP5_Input ,
        dP5_InputTransType ,
        dP6_Input ,
        dP6_InputTransType ,
        dP7_Input ,
        dP7_InputTransType ,
        dP8_Input ,
        dP8_InputTransType ,
        dP9_Input ,
        dP9_InputTransType ,
        dP10_Input ,
        dP10_InputTransType ,
        dP11_Input ,
        dP11_InputTransType ,
        dTimestamp 
        FROM [DB100].[DB].[dbo].[DCN_'+@SQLname+']
        UNION ALL
'
IF @i = @count SET @sql = LEFT(@sql,LEN(@sql) - 15)
--PRINT @sql
EXEC (@sql)

SET @i=@i+1
END
IF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##tab') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE ##tab
END
END

GO
```

Comment: Please realize that you have concurrency issues here because of the global temp table. You also have some performance challenges because your main query has nonSARGable predicates. Last but not least I would recommend not using a while loop to build up a dynamic sql string like this. You could do this whole process a lot simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the problem. I get that you are trying to build some dynamic sql and `UNION ALL`. The problem is that you execute the `@sql` in the loop while the statement is still building. So basically you build and execute `@sql` every iteration. Move the final execute outside of the loop. I have shortened your code to show where the issue is.

Oh and the reason it was working when you comment out the `insert` into the temp table is because since there were no rows in that table you never get into the loop.

```
BEGIN
SELECT @SQLname=SQLname, @myMonth=myMonth, @myYear=myYear FROM ##tab WHERE id=@i 

SET @sql = '
  YOUR CODE 
  UNION ALL'
IF @i = @count SET @sql = LEFT(@sql,LEN(@sql) - 15)
--PRINT @sql

/*HERE YOU EXECUTE WHILE IN LOOP SO THE LAST LINE IS UNION ALL*/
EXEC (@sql)
SET @i=@i+1
END
```

Here's the fix

```
SET @i=1
/* Set @sql outside of loop */
SET @sql = ''
SELECT @count= COUNT(*) FROM ##tab
WHILE @i <= @count

BEGIN
SELECT @SQLname=SQLname, @myMonth=myMonth, @myYear=myYear FROM ##tab WHERE id=@i 

/* Modified this to add to @sql each interation to build your select statement.*/
SET @sql = @sql + '
  select 1 
  UNION ALL'

IF @i = @count SET @sql = LEFT(@sql,LEN(@sql) - 15)

SET @i=@i+1
END

/* Moved exec out of loop*/
EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: That is not the problem. The PRINT is coming out looking good.

Comment: @dbahiker That's because you are printing each iteration so the results look like its one big print but actually it's 6. Below your print add another line `PRINT 'STATEMENT EXECUTED'` and you'll see what I mean

Comment: Gotcha, ok Im looking for solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes give me a second to post it

Comment: @dbahiker please see updated answer. You need to set `sql` before the loop just like you did `i`. Then change the way you set `sql` just like how you increment `i`. Then execute `sql` outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Why is the union ALL at the bottom of your dynamic SQL query?  It's where the error comes from...union all combines two seperate select statements with like fields

simple example:

```
 select 1 
 union all
 select 2
```

this will return 2 rows...1 and 2.

Here you have it here with nothing following it.  Remove the union all, unless you have another statement to run under it, in which case...include the other statement in your code.

Comment: The query is setup to be built in a while loop so the union all is there to join them together.  There is a removal step in the IF i = Count that will eliminate it if there is only one query needed.  I assume something is wrong with the way it is being built.  Take your PRINT @sql output and put into a query window, looking for errors.

Comment: I have it with the UNION ALL because I'm SELECTing more then 2 SELECT statements. The base query could have 9 results and then I will have 9 SELECT statements all with UNION ALL between them. Then on the last loop you will see I remove LENGTH by 15 characters.

Comment: Earl G yes I'm about to run it fine when I PRINT it. Also works fine when run the whole thing as a query and not a Stored Procedure

Comment: is the loops iteration leaving a union all at the end of the query then?